# Native Module(Android) linking in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to link my "hello world"(android project ) in react-native, to just have a proper idea of native module linking in react native.

Any help with steps to be followed for this will be appreciable.

Comment: react native also comes under native development. What exactly you want. Want to do "Hello world" in react native?

Comment: No,i want to link an existing android project to react native .

Comment: i.e. java based android coding to react native?

Comment: Yes @Arnold Brown.

Comment: have you gone through react-native official link?

Comment: yes, I have gone through but still not getting the exact way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gone through official document again and now I got the point -https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html